# Copy Editor / Strunk & White badge: Description error or bug (tag edits)?

Tags: support, edits, badges

The descriptions for the Strunk & White Badge and Copy Editor Badges have the following text:

> Edit [X] posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)

But actually, when I edit tags, I've noticed that my score of number of posts edited for the badges goes up.

Thus my question: is the description wrong (outdated) or is there a bug in the system?

Comment: No repro here when editing your question's tags.

Comment: @Frédéric Thanks! The way you formulate your comment makes me think that "tag edits" are not editing tag wiki posts but rather editing how a post is tagged. That would certainly explain my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have misunderstood the description.
In particular I might have misunderstood what a "tag edit" is. 
I understood a "tag edit" to be an edit of the tag description.
It might be that a "tag edit" refers to changing how a post is tagged. 
Thank you @Frédéric Hamidi for putting me on the right track with your comment.

Comment: "*an edit of the tag description"* is a tag **wiki** edit...

Answer (score 0):

A tag edit would be removing or adding a tag on your question.  Changing the wiki of a tag is a tag wiki edit and is included towards the editor badges.

So since you are editing the "description" of the tags that is a valid edit and you should see your counter increasing.

Here is a [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)